# Oracle query for displaying View meta data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For historical reasons, we have a set of views calling other materialized view or tables (local or through DB Link)

I need to generate a report, which list all the tables or MVs each view is calling. at moment I manage to create this query:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM cols c, obj o
  WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = o.object_name
  AND o.object_type = 'VIEW'     
  ORDER BY c.table_name, c.column_id;
```

its almost there, but still missing the table/MV name of where the view is selecting from,
and what type of thing we are selecting from (a MV or Table , through DB Link or synonym )

anyone could help

Comment: Look at ALL_DEPENDENCIES.  It should show you the objects on which the view is dependent.  Linking it back to All_Objects will give you the object type.

Comment: Just one other note: I often use queries similar to `Select * from dictionary where UPPER(comments) like '%DEP%'` when trying to find where meta data is stored to build more dynamic functions, or to research how a DB is doing a particular thing.  I've found I use ALL_DEPENDENCIES, All_OBJECTS, ALL_SOURCE, DBA_ROLE_PRIVS and ALL_TAB_COLS the most.  One thing to be aware of though is that there are times you may not have the needed permissions to see all rows (a DBA may see more than you unless you're operating as a DBA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this...

I expanded it to look at all Objects and then limit by schema (owner).

```
 SELECT O.Owner, O.object_name, C.ColumN_Name, C.Data_Type, O.Object_type, O.Object_Type, 
    AD.Referenced_name, AD.Referenced_Type
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLS c
  INNER JOIN ALL_OBJECTS O
    ON c.TABLE_NAME = o.object_name
    and C.Owner = O.Owner
  INNER JOIN ALL_DEPENDENCIES AD
    on AD.Name = O.Object_Name
    and AD.Owner = O.Owner
  WHERE  o.object_type = 'VIEW' 
  and O.owner = user
  ORDER BY c.table_name, c.column_id;
```

Comment: thanks I did this which kinda works too SELECT a.NAME view_name,
  A.REFERENCED_NAME,
  referenced_type,
  type
FROM obj o,
  ALL_DEPENDENCIES a
WHERE a.NAME      = o.object_name
AND o.object_type = 'VIEW'
AND OWNER         = 'xxx'
  --and referenced_type != 'TABLE'
  --and type != 'VIEW'
ORDER BY view_name;    now it displays all the mviews the views are calling, I am trying to get deeper, which is finding all the relationship of all the mviews.... you have any clue?

Comment: You'd have to use a hierarchical query (Connect by prior) (or a recursive query using Common Table Expressions (CTE))  In both cases you're taking the dependencies and looking for the dependencies on it until no further dependencies are found.  Referenced_name becomes the object_name and then your finding it's references (looping recursively until no further references are found)  this looping is done via CTE or connect by prior, or writing a cursor,  I think a CTe or connect by is likely the easiest though.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a variation of this type of query that you want to use to look at my view dependencies.

```
SELECT dd.owner view_owner,
  dd.NAME view_name,
  dd.referenced_owner,
  dd.referenced_name,
  dd.referenced_object_name
FROM
  (SELECT dep.owner,
    dep.NAME,
    dep.referenced_owner,
    dep.referenced_name,
    dep.TYPE,
    dep.owner
    || '.'
    || dep.NAME object_name,
    dep.referenced_owner
    || '.'
    || dep.referenced_name referenced_object_name
  FROM dba_dependencies dep
  INNER JOIN dba_objects obj
  ON dep.referenced_name   = obj.object_name
  AND dep.referenced_owner = obj.owner
  WHERE dep.TYPE          IN ('VIEW','MATERIALIZED VIEW', 'TABLE')
  AND obj.object_type     IN ('VIEW','MATERIALIZED VIEW', 'TABLE')
  ) dd
  START WITH dd.owner         = :l_owner
AND dd.NAME                   = :l_view
AND dd.TYPE                   = 'VIEW'
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR 1  =1
AND PRIOR dd.referenced_owner =dd.owner
AND PRIOR dd.referenced_name  =dd.NAME
```

This query just cycles through dependencies from a hierarchical perspective starting from the view (:l_owner, :l_view)